# cannot install a certain module on google-collab

Tags: linux, perl, cpan

i try to install the module on the Google-Colab - but it does not work

```
!cpan install CPAN::Authors
```

**Output**:

```
Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better logging
Reading '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Mon, 06 Mar 2023 12:41:02 GMT
>(error): Could not expand [CPAN::Authors]. Check the module name.
>(info): I can suggest names if you install one of Text::Levenshtein::XS, Text::Levenshtein::Damerau::XS, Text::Levenshtein, and Text::Levenshtein::Damerau::PP
>(info): and you provide the -x option on invocation.
>(error): Skipping CPAN::Authors because I couldn't find a matching namespace.
```

but it of course exists:  see https://metacpan.org/pod/Parse::CPAN::Authors::Author

well it looks like i cannot load the module - but it still exists
what is the cause that this does not work at all!?

Comment: *"!cpan install CPAN::Authors"* : I think you meant to install this module: https://metacpan.org/pod/Parse::CPAN::Authors. Try run `!cpan Parse::CPAN::Authors`

Comment: many thanks dear Hakon - awesome - i tiry this outl

Comment: !cpan install Parse::CPAN::Authors

and then it works perfectly ...

solved - thread solved & many thanks

Comment: btw - if i am running this - - i get some errors.. see above ... the enlarged threadstart

Comment: *"my $authors = !cpan Parse::CPAN::Authors->new();"* : Try remove `!cpan` it does not belong inside a Perl script

Comment: *"use CPAN Parse::CPAN::Authors;*" : This line is also a syntax error. Try remove `CPAN`. Like this `use Parse::CPAN::Authors`

Comment: *"btw - if i am running this - - i get some errors.. see above"* Please open a new follow-up question if the errors are not related to the original question. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions

Comment: 1) Don't post answers to questions in the question. Post them as Answers, even if it's to your own question. 2) Don't replace one question with a completely different question. Ask that as a separate Question. // Rolled back these two changes.

Comment: [You are using Python to execute a Perl program, you are loading the wrong module, and you have a stray `!cpan` in the middle of the program.]

Answer (score 2):

You linked to Parse::CPAN::Authors::Author, but you tried installing CPAN::Authors.

Use

```perl
cpan Parse::CPAN::Authors::Author
```

(Note that lack of the word `install`, as well.)